# Webscraping Multi page issue

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I am trying to **scrape** the following link "https://eprocure.gov.in/eprocure/app;jsessionid=9AD8A7A17E1B2868527E25799DBE45A2.eprocgep2?page=FrontEndLatestActiveTenders&service=page"  with bs4 in python .For the first page everything seems to be ok .But When I am navigating to next page the URL pattern is changing completely .Now here is the next page URL pattern :"https://eprocure.gov.in/eprocure/app?component=%24TablePages.linkPage&page=FrontEndLatestActiveTenders&service=direct&session=T&sp=AFrontEndLatestActiveTenders%2Ctable&sp=2"..Due to the pattern change I can not automate the scraping process for every page ..But when I try to **scrape** the second page manually the soup object can not fetch any of the tags .But in network inspect showing those tags for second page ...can any one solve the issue ?? **scrape** all of the pages.. please share your solution

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried.

Comment: cant paste the whole code , do u have a mail id or skype id ...it will be helpful

Comment: You can add the code which is relevant to the question. In particular how you were planning to navigate through pages.

Comment: productLinks = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'id' : re.compile(r'linkPage.*')})  <br/>
page_number_list=[1]  <br/>
for item in productLinks:  <br/>
    page_number_list.append(int(item.text))  <br/>
    
url_list = ["{}&pageNum={}".format(Base_url, str(page)) for page in page_number_list]  <br/>

Comment: @ShirsenduMazumdar i'm not seeing any issue with the links provided !

Comment: @ahmed American , are u successfully able to fetch second link??

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away lik rubbish.